# How can create an isolated JVM?

Tags: java, security, jvm, javac

How  can I create JVM with fewer cpu and ram (resources) and give other  access to it, while also ensuring that they cannot manipulate or view  files or data of my system?

I want to create a web interface java compiler which everyone can use and would not like if other can manipulate my system.

Comment: You can run it in a VM like https://www.virtualbox.org/

Answer (score 3):

If you use [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) or another VM you can

- choose the OS, it doesn't have to be the same.
- choose all the files it can see
- choose how much CPUs and memory it can use.
- make it hard to break out of the virtual host and into the real host.

Comment: ^This. Sandboxing a VM itself is much harder than sandboxing an entire OS :)